# Absolute scale - Rotating scale vector

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Need to get global absolute scale of object to display it with **OpenGL**.
When I just multiply scale vectors of parents and children, I get absolute scale for world axes space. When I rotate object, it scales along global axes, not local.

I decided that I need to rotate scale vector too. But:

1. When I am trying to rotate it with direction vector - it values sometimes are going to `0`, and scale too.

   ```
   { scale.x * forward.x , scale.y * forward.y , scale.z * forward.z }
   ```
2. When I am trying to rotate it with `glm::rotate`, it makes unexpected results, like infinite rotating/scaling, wrench and other effects on meshes.

   ```
   auto globalScale = glm::vec3(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
   globalScale = glm::rotate(globalScale, rotation.x, {1,0,0});
   globalScale = glm::rotate(globalScale, rotation.y, {0,1,0});
   globalScale = glm::rotate(globalScale, rotation.z, {0,0,1});
   ```

My rendering code:

```
void Render(Material *mat, Transform* tr){

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);

    // Get object transformations
    Vector3 pos = tr->globalPosition();
    Vector3 rot = tr->globalRotation();
    Vector3 scale = (tr->globalScale());
    auto globalScale = glm::vec3(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);

    // First, scaling, then rotating, then translating in world space
    // ( Initially all objects rendering starts at (0,0,0) )
    glScaled(globalScale.x, globalScale.y, globalScale.z);
    glRotatef(rot.x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rot.y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rot.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslated(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

    // Rendering 

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,vertexArray);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,normalArray);

    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);
    glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,uvArray);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,numVerts);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Rolling transformations back

    glTranslated(-pos.x, -pos.y, -pos.z);
    glRotated(-rot.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glRotated(-rot.y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotated(-rot.x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScaled(1/globalScale.x, 1/globalScale.y, 1/globalScale.z);
}
```

Rendering call:

```
void RenderObject(GameObject* go){
    for(auto goc : go->children)
        goc->Update<MeshRenderer>();//RenderObject(goc);
}

void RenderScene(){
    auto scene = EditorInstance::GetSingleton()->currentScene;
    for(auto go : scene->hierarchy){
        RenderObject(go);
        if(auto mr = (go->GetComponent<Camera>())){
            mr->Update();
        }
    }
}

... render->setOnRender(RenderScene); ...
```

Main rendering method:

```
int render()
{
#ifdef EDITOR
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer for rendering
        glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT); // Push our glEnable and glViewport states
        DrawGrid(100);
#else
    if(NukeOGL::getSingleton() != this){
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo); // Bind our frame buffer for rendering
        glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT); // Push our glEnable and glViewport states
    }
#endif

    //glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity ();

    gluLookAt(transform->position.x,
                      transform->position.y,
                      transform->position.z,
                      transform->position.x + transform->direction().x,
                      transform->position.y + transform->direction().y,
                      transform->position.z + transform->direction().z,
                      0.0,
                      1.0,
                      0.0);

    if(_onRender.size() > 0)
        for(auto _rn : _onRender){
            _rn();
        }

#ifdef EDITOR
    glPopAttrib(); // Restore our glEnable and glViewport states
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0); // Unbind our texture
#else
    if(NukeOGL::getSingleton() != this){
        glPopAttrib(); // Restore our glEnable and glViewport states
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0); // Unbind our texture
    }
#endif
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(_onGUI.size() > 0)
        for(auto _rn : _onGUI){
            _rn();
        }

    glutSwapBuffers();
    //glutPostRedisplay();
    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing wrong? What I should do to make it right scale from local to world space?

Comment: You should edit your question and add enough code to see where your problem is.

Comment: Again, the code you've updated may be applied to all objects (as defined in glBegin, glEnd pairs). And I don't see any `glMatrixMode` call (default is *model view matrix*).

Comment: Yeah, I know a bit about rendering and have made this code according to tutorial. But, I doning that for every object in hierarchy that had renderer component, recursively. Can  you tell me more detailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale and rotation are *linear transformations*, their effects are relative to distance to origin of coordinates system. You must apply them in a proper order and with a proper origin each.

I explain in 2D so it's easier to understand.

Say you have a rectangle of size axb, whose center is at `{cx,cy}` and you want to scale and rotate (in this order). Then you first translate to `{0,0}` then scale, then rotate, then translate it back to `{cx,cy}`. Since each transformation is defined by a matrix, and usually OpenGL matrices are defined in column-mayor order, the composed matrix for this object may be:

```
MObj_i = MObj_i_trans(cx,cy) * MObj_i_rot(cangle, caxis) * MObj_i_sca(cfactor) * MObj_i_trans(-cx,-cy)
```

After you do those transformations for each object (with its own center/scale/rotation each) you want a "global" scale and rotation. Again you need a center of scale/rotation:

```
MGlobal = MGlo_trans(gx,gy) * MGlo_rot(gangle, gaxis) * MGlo_sca(gfactor) * MGlo_trans(-gx,-gy)
```

Usually the world center is `{0,0}' so you can avoid translations:

```
MGlobal = MGlo_rot(gangle, gaxis) * MGlo_sca(gfactor)
```

The good news is that the transformations can be combined into an only matrix. So, for each object, you apply the matrix:

```
MObjec_i = MGlobal * MObj_i
```

If you use **glm** for these maths, don't forget to inializate an *Identity matrix*:

```
glm::mat4 objScale(1.0);
objScale(objScale, vec3(fx, fy, fz));
glm::mat4 objRotate(1.0);
objRotate(objRotate, angle, vec3(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z));
etc.
```

Comment: I'm doing the same: first, scaling(at the start, (0,0)), next rotating, then translating, drawing, and then backwards. But it makes no changes. It still scaling in global space.